# How to find a public company's balance sheet and income statement?

Tags: balance-sheet, financial-statements, sec, income-statement

In the U.S., if a company's stock is publicly traded, it is legally required to file public financial disclosures to Securities and Exchange Commission.

**How can I find the balance sheet and income statement (which should be part of such filings) of public companies?** For example, I tried searching for "Whole Foods" on SEC's website (https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html) with the following list of filings displayed: https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000865436&type=&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40. However, I do not see any document that indicates it is/contains the balance sheet or income statement.

Comment: May I know why there are the downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The balance sheet and income statements are located in the 10-K and 10-Q filings for all publicly traded companies. [It will be Item 8](https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answersreada10khtm.html).

Answer (score 2):

Filter by the filings when you look at the search results.  The 10-K will include the annual report, which included fiscal year-end financial statements.  Quarterly reports and statements are in the 10-Q filing.

The filing will include a LOT of other information, but there should be a section called "Financial Statements" or something similar that will include all pertinent financials statements.

You can also find "normalized" balance sheets and income statements on the "finance" pages of the main web search sites (Google, Yahoo, MSN) and other sites that provide stock quotes.  If you're looking to do basic comparisons versus in-depth statement analysis those may be sufficient for you.

Answer (score 1):

The websites of the most publicly traded companies publish their quarterly and annual financials.  Check the investor relations sections out at the ones you want to look at.